# Relative KPI value

Tags: mdx, sql-server-2012-datatools

Im working with MS Analytics Tools. I would like to create a KPI showing monthly change of number of sold products. I have my measure `[Measures].[Sold Count]` and dimension [Date].
Moreover the goal should be "increased by `1.5%` in selected month".

My problem is: I have no idea what to write in `Status expression` and `Trend expression`. I know that ParallelPeriod is something I should use.

I assume that `Value expression` can be just `[Measures].[Sold Count]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[Sold Growth] as ( ( [Date].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Sold Count] ) / ( [Date].CurrentMember.Lag(1), [Measures].[Sold Count] ) - 1) *100
Member [Measures].[Sold Target] as ( [Date].CurrentMember.Lag(1), [Measures].[Sold Count] ) * 1.015

Select <a set of months> on Rows,
{ [Measure].[Sold Count], [Measures].[Sold Growth], [Measures].[Sold Target]} on Columns

From [Cube]
```

Remark: Using [Date].CurrentMember.Lag(1) assumes your [Date].CurrentMember is at the month level. If it's not you should probably use ParallelPeriods or another date function that can retrieve the previous month value;